# Not able to create vaadin project using maven in eclipse

Tags: maven, vaadin7

Hi I am currently building vaadin project using maven but getting below error.

Unable to create project from archetype [com.vaadin:vaadin-archetype-application:LATEST -> ]

stack trace

```
org.apache.maven.archetype.exception.ArchetypeNotConfigured: Archetype com.vaadin:vaadin-archetype-application:7.1.13 is not configured
    Property theme is missing.
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.generator.DefaultFilesetArchetypeGenerator.generateArchetype(DefaultFilesetArchetypeGenerator.java:142)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.generator.DefaultArchetypeGenerator.processFileSetArchetype(DefaultArchetypeGenerator.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.generator.DefaultArchetypeGenerator.generateArchetype(DefaultArchetypeGenerator.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.generator.DefaultArchetypeGenerator.generateArchetype(DefaultArchetypeGenerator.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.archetype.DefaultArchetype.generateProjectFromArchetype(DefaultArchetype.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.createArchetypeProjects0(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:761)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$4.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:710)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$4.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1305)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.createArchetypeProjects(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:708)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.MavenProjectWizard$5.doCreateMavenProjects(MavenProjectWizard.java:244)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.AbstactCreateMavenProjectJob$1.doCreateMavenProjects(AbstactCreateMavenProjectJob.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.AbstractCreateMavenProjectsOperation.run(AbstractCreateMavenProjectsOperation.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.AbstactCreateMavenProjectJob.runInWorkspace(AbstactCreateMavenProjectJob.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

please help on this I am completely novice

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try creating the project from command line. To do this follow this tutorial: https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Using+Vaadin+with+Maven

```
mvn archetype:generate \
-DarchetypeGroupId=com.vaadin \
-DarchetypeArtifactId=vaadin-archetype-clean \
-DarchetypeVersion=LATEST \
-DgroupId=your.company \
-DartifactId=project-name \
-Dversion=1.0 \
-Dpackaging=war
```

Comment: I got my issue resolved actually from eclipse while creating vaadin project we need to add theme as variable....now its working fine